# Shortcut to insert plaintext?

Tags: text

Oftentimes I would find it useful to insert plaintext, to not be evaluated as input, right next to my input code. Is there a shortcut key to insert such a plaintext input box? I have relied on comments (shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>), but as I use a touchscreen display and a small Bluetooth keyboard, it is a real hassle to select a line of text and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. So I was looking for something easier.

Comment: You can select up to the beginning of a line with Shift + Home

Comment: @ssch I know that! But I am typing on this [Logitech Bluetooth keyboard](http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-920-003390-Tablet-Keyboard-Android/dp/B0054L8N7M) which means I have to hit the FN key just to hit the home key. That means to do SHIFT + HOME and select the line, I have touch the screen at the start of the line, then hit FN + LEFT ARROW + SHIFT.

Comment: For everyone's benefit, [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html) is the answer I found.

Comment: ALT+7 is for Text style, [ALT+0 is for input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TextStyling.html), ...

Comment: Fof, if you have found a solution that indeed satisfies you, consider posting it as an **answer** for your own question for everyone's benefit! You could even accept it if no better answer appears after some time.

Comment: @IstvánZachar accepting the answer to my own question looks lame though. Why don't you answer it and I'll accept it?

Comment: One other question I had (maybe needs to have its own question), is how to set the default Text style (e.g. its font, font size,), you know, for when you hit CTRL+ ENTER?

Comment: FoF, don't feel bad due to self-acceptance, happened to many of us. If it's helpful for the community, everyone should set aside hes/her own concerns :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar, answer is posted.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone's benefit, [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html) is the answer I found. 
`CTRL+(` then `CTRL+)`.